# PDE(plugins development in java)

Tags: eclipse, plugins

i am running the execute method but i gives some error on the logError in the following code. Please help!

```
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        //get the active window
        IWorkbenchWindow window=HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
        if(window==null)
            return null;
        //get the active page
        IWorkbenchPage page= window.getActivePage();
        if(page==null)
            return null;
        //open and activate the Favorite view
        try{
            page.showView(ViewPart.ID);
        }
        catch(PartInitException e){
            FavoritesLog.logError("Failed to open the favorites view", e);


        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exception you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what error you got there, but you should try wrapping the inner part of your execute code in a UIJob.
Something like this:

```
public Object execute(final ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException { //get the active window
    Job job = new UIJob("Show View") {
        public IStatus runInUIThread(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
            IWorkbenchWindow window=HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
            if(window==null) { 
                return Status.CANCEL_STATUS; 
            }
            //get the active page 
            IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage(); 
            if(page==null) {
                return return Status.CANCEL_STATUS;
            }
            //open and activate the Favorite view 
            try{ 
                page.showView(ViewPart.ID); 
            } catch(PartInitException e){  
                FavoritesLog.logError("Failed to open the favorites view", e);
                return return Status.CANCEL_STATUS;
            }
            return Status.OK_STATUS;
    };
    job.schedule();
    return null;
}
```